# Winforms User Input Validation

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, validation

Most of my work is SQL database driven desktop apps using winforms.  I'm now using Entity Framework - Code First with the typical Program (UI), Model and DataAccess layers.  I've always done data validation at the UI level using the errorprovider.  With Entity Framework I could now do some validation like required entry on the entity.  I would still have to do some validation at the UI level.  Question 1: Is splitting the validation like this OK or not advised? Question 2: Should I do form validation in each forms class or have a separate validation class used by all forms?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to Validate? does every form have and or require validation? if so then you pretty much answered your own question..